# Permalink Redirect Rule

Tags: wordpress

If we have a website with the following with the permalink rule: /%postname%/0%post_id%/

https://example.com/post-title/0post-id/

Now i want to do is if anyone clicks: https://example.com/post-title/ it redirects to https://example.com/post-title/0post-id/ automatically.

How can we do it?